# Get another view in onClick() method

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have two buttons in my `RecyclerView` layout with ids `button1` and `button2`.

Here is my `RecyclerView` adapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;

    private List<Data> dataList;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<Data> dataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dataList = dataList;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public Data data;

        public Button button1, button2;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            button1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            button2 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        }

        public void setData(Data data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int id = v.getId();

            if (id == R.id.button1) {
                clickButton(v);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public DataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_layout, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Data data = dataList.get(position);

        holder.setData(data);

        //
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public void clickButton(View v) {
        Button button1 = (Button) v;

        // HOW DO I GET BUTTON2?
    }
}
```

How can I get `button2` in my `clickButton()` method, since `v` only returns the view for `button1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this :

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setTag(v.getId())
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.button1:
               clickButton(v);
               break;
            case R.id.button2:
               clickButton(v);
               break;
        }
    }
```

And then in clickButton method, just get tag and check the id to get required button and use as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass both buttons from the click listener itself like -

```
clickButton(button1, button2);
```

Reason is `button1` and `button2` are member variables of a `ViewHolder` class in which you implemented `onClickListener`.